# OVH Public Cloud Storage, Duplicity, Openstack, Swfit REGION NAME issue

Tags: swift, openstack, ovh

Thanks for reading me !

I do daily backups of my OVH Public Cloud projects and other on OVH Swift/Openstack Public Cloud storages using Duplicity on Debian 8. Everything works fine except for the location of the containers that are created by my scripts.

Indeed, while I specify "export SWIFT_REGIONNAME ="GRA3"" so that the containers are created in Gravelines ("GRA3"), they are all without exception created in Warsaw ("WAW1").

I am copying you here my normalized Duplicity script, if more experienced OpenStack or Duplicity users do not pass there I hope they can help me!

Script Example :

```html
SWIFT_USERNAME="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
export SWIFT_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export SWIFT_AUTHURL="https://auth.cloud.ovh.net/v2.0/"
export SWIFT_AUTHVERSION="2"
export SWIFT_TENANTNAME="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export SWIFT_REGIONNAME="GRA3"

duplicity --verbosity notice \
--num-retries 1 \
--asynchronous-upload \
--cf-backend swift \
--full-if-older-than 7D \
--volsize 100 \
--encrypt-key "$enc_key" \
--sign-key "$sign_key" \
"${src}" "${dest}"

unset SWIFT_USERNAME SWIFT_PASSWORD SWIFT_AUTHURL SWIFT_AUTHVERSION SWIFT_TENANTNAME SWIFT_REGIONNAME PASSPHRASE SIGN_PASSPHRASE
```

am open to any trail or advices that would explain this problem, i'm new to duplicity so i think i did a mistake i just dont know what it is !

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem and came with a solution, with an older version of duplicity the environment variable SWIFT_REGIONNAME wasn't working but with the lastest version 0.7.18.2 works perfectly. Maybe your issue is the same. Hope this help you. Greetings.